# API usage forbidden, use API-V2?

Tags: soundcloud

I've researched the official SoundCloud API, and I couldn't get it to work. It was always returning **403 Forbidden** error as a response. I've tried inserting the `client_id` and the Authorization header with OAuth token.

But, I've tried to use API-v2 and that seems to be working. Is there any documentation on how to use this version and is it legal?

Also, is there a way to fix this problem with the official API? I cannot register an app since SoundCloud has closed it down years ago.

Comment: Well, the fact that SoundCloud closed registrations of new apps might be the culprit. They are the sovereign over their API and it's usage. While it they still support legacy apps, they have no intention to support the old API for new apps. This is quite common in the "API business".